# Separate data and presentation in deep nested component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to separate data fetching and presentation layer when there are nested deep levels.

For example, I need to build a tree-like comments system like HackerNews or Reddit.com, which is collapsable.

I want to fetch the data in a container then use it in the presentation layer. I use a recursive `Comment` component design. Since the comments contain children comments I need to fetch data in nested child component too. So aside from fetching data in parent I add a callback in each `Comment` component just to set the states for each `Comment` just for iterating the children comments.

I find myself muddling up states very quickly when I add the collapsable functionality because I need to calculate and store the children count for every comment.

Any quick solution for that?